# Getting error while running directfb example in vaware ubuntu with 32 bit system

Tags: directfb

While Running df_andi example i am getting this output so can ayone tell me why i am getting this.

```
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'SigHandler' (9163) [CRITICAL - OTHER/0] <8392704>...

   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~| DirectFB 1.7.1 |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        (c) 2012-2013  DirectFB integrated media GmbH
        (c) 2001-2013  The world wide DirectFB Open Source Community
        (c) 2000-2004  Convergence (integrated media) GmbH
      ----------------------------------------------------------------

(*) DirectFB/Core: Single Application Core. (2014-10-17 10:53) 
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'Fusion Dispatch' (9164) [MESSAGING - OTHER/0] <8392704>...
 (!!!)  *** ONCE [Joystick sends JS_EVENT_INIT events, make sure it has been calibrated using 'jscal -c'
] *** [joystick.c:103 in joystick_handle_event()]
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'Joystick Input' (9165) [INPUT - OTHER/0] <8392704>...
(*) DirectFB/Input: Joystick 0.9 (directfb.org)
(*) DirectFB/Input: Hot-plug detection enabled with Input Hub Driver 
(*) DirectFB/Genefx: MMX detected and enabled
(*) DirectFB/Graphics: MMX Software Rasterizer 0.7 (directfb.org)
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'Dummy Display' (9166) [OUTPUT - OTHER/0] <8392704>...
(*) DirectFB/Core/WM: Default 0.3 (directfb.org)
(*) Direct/Thread: Started 'Genefx' (9167) [DEFAULT - OTHER/0] <8392704>...
(*) Direct/Interface: Loaded 'FT2' implementation of 'IDirectFBFont'.
(*) Direct/Interface: Loaded 'PNG' implementation of 'IDirectFBImageProvider'.
(*) Direct/Interface: Loaded 'JPEG' implementation of 'IDirectFBImageProvider'.
^C(!) [SigHandler       9257.891,927] ( 9163) Direct/Signals:                --> Caught signal 2 (sent by the kernel) <--
(-) [SigHandler       9259.025,425] ( 9163) Direct/Trap:               Raising signal 2 from SigHandler...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no error, you posted your Debug messages in the question.

Its just you need to set the FRAMEBUFFER as you are using vmware.

post the output of `fbset -i`

There you can see what is your default FRAMEBUFFER and you need to change it to -> `/dev/fb0`